# On disconnecting ChromeCast from one device is stopping receiver application

Tags: android, chromecast

Two or more android device are connected in to the same chromecast receiver  application. And when i disconnect from anyone of the device the chromecast receiver application is stopped. 
The issue is occured after updating play-services-cast-framework:**9.4.0** to play-services-cast-framework: **9.8.0**.
Have also tried **10.0.1** version also issue is still there.

Any suggestions/directions are much appreciated.

Comment: You may check on this [related issue on GitHub](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android/issues/25). "*It depends on your application; there is an api `(VideoCastManager.setStopOnDisconnect(boolean))` that if you call and pass a false to it, it will not stop the application when you disconnect, assuming you are not doing anything else in that respect in your application.*" You need to register Custom Receiver. In this receiver, you have to implement one Media channel and one custom data channel.

Comment: @abielita :- Thanks for u reply, but I have already tried this and also by default (VideoCastManager.setStopOnDisconnect(boolean)) is false. but i tried it by sending false to . Still the issue is there. But when i downgrade to 9,4.6 it got worked. I belive its the issue with cast framework liberary version above 9.8.0. I have raise the issue to google  too